# How can I find the limit of the complex function: $f\left(z\right)=\frac{z\left(e^{\frac{1}{z}}-1\right)}{e^z-1}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, laurent-series, singularity

I was asked to determine the type of the isolated singularity of the function $f(z)$ at $z=0$:
$$f\left(z\right)=\frac{z\left(e^{\frac{1}{z}}-1\right)}{e^z-1}$$
I know that if the function's limit doesn't exist at $z=0$, then we can say that the function has an essential singular point at $z=0$.
I wasn't able to show that the limit doesn't exist. Also, I was wondering if there is a way to find the full Laurent expansion.

Comment: The generating function of the Bernoulli numbers may help you finding the Laurent series. It is $z/(e^z-1)$. This function has a removable singularity at $z=0$, so the type of singularity of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ will be determined by that of $e^{1/z}$. Can you show that the latter is an essential one?

Comment: Yes, I was able to show that $\lim _{z\to 0^+}\left(f\left(z\right)\right)\neq\lim \:_{z\to \:0^-}\left(f\left(z\right)\right)$ thus, from what I learned, z=0 is an essential one. However why is that true to split the function, and say that  $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ is the one to determine the type? maybe I misunderstood you

Comment: Because you can just focus on the important bit. But as I understand you solved the problem. Can you see that $f(z)$ is analytic in a punctured neighbourhood of $0$?

Comment: I just noticed that I accidentally wrote limz→0+(f(z))≠limz→0−(f(z)) instead of $\lim _{z\to 0^+}\left(e^{\frac{1}{z}}\right)=\lim _{z\to 0^-}\left(e^{\frac{1}{z}}\right)$ . And, yes I see that f(z)  is analytic in a punctured neighbourhood of 0.

Comment: Then you are done since the limit of $z/(e^z-1)$ exists at $z=0$ (it is $1$).

Comment: Now I see that. Thank you so much for your help :)